# Is there a way to set :except => { :no_release => true } for all Capistrano tasks by default?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I have an app server and elasticsearch on another.

I setup a search roles as follows:

```
role :search, 'search.server.com', :no_release => true
```

I have 3 different stages - prod, stage, experiment

I want all commmands to run on the app server, except a couple on the elasticsearch server.

It seems I have to add `:except => { :no_release => true }` on all my tasks to get this functionality.

Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up multiple roles and specify the no_release on the ones that's needed.
Tasks can be run for the specified roles only, example:

```
role :search, "ex.com", :no_release => true
role :app, "ex.com"

task :run_for_both, :roles => [:app, :search] do
  run "echo 'my command'"
end

task :run_on_app, :roles => :app, :search do
  run "echo 'my command on app role'"
end
```